# change image based on dropdown vanilla js

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, dropdown

Hi Im new to javascript

i'm trying to change an image based on what the user chooses from a select input.

i want to link what what the user chooses from the select and an array

id also love for it to be in javascript and not jquery

this is what ive managed so far but im stuck with why its telling me undefined

```
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    .cta {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: red;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <div>
    <label for="fullname">First name:</label>
    <input name="fullname" class="sig_fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <br>
    <label>Job title</label>
    <input class="sig_jobTitle" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
    <br>
    <label>phone number</label>
    <input class="sig_mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile">
    <br>
    <label for="company">Company:</label>

    <select name="company" class="sig_company">
      <option value="">please select</option>
      <option value="">company1</option>
      <option value="">company2</option>
      <option value="">company3</option>
    </select>


  </div>

  <a class="cta" onclick="generate();">Generate</a>


  <div>first name: <span class="name"></span></div>
  <div>Job title: <span class="job"></span></div>
  <div>Phone number: <span class="number"></span></div>
  <img class="companylogo" src="./img/example.jpg">



  <script>

    function generate() {

      var fullName = document.querySelector(".sig_fullName").value;
      var jobTitle = document.querySelector(".sig_jobTitle").value;
      var Mobile = document.querySelector(".sig_mobile").value;

      document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = fullName;
      document.querySelector(".job").innerHTML = jobTitle;
      document.querySelector(".number").innerHTML = Mobile;

      var swap = [
        './img/company1.svg',
        './img/company2.svg',
        './img/company3.png',
      ]

      var logo = document.querySelector(".companylogo");
        var dropdown = document.querySelector(".sig_company");
        logo.src = swap.value;

    }

  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the way your accessing a property within the `swap` array

Try

```
logo.src = swap[dropdown.selectedIndex - 1];
```

The dropdown will have a selectedIndex value, it's 0 based like arrays, but because the first value is "please select" we need to minus one from the selectedIndex to correctly align it with the array of images.